# Windows 10 stuck on wake from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have the following build:

```
Intel i7-4790k
Asus Z97-PRO
Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD
Windows 10 Build 1511
```

My PC sometimes gets stuck on a wake and doesn't respond till I reset it. I put the computer to sleep every night and never restart except for maintenance or upgrades.

Roughly once a week, the PC gets stuck on wake. I tried disabling hybrid sleep, but this did not solve the problem. The motherboard is stuck at the Q-code 30 (The code for a wake from S3 sleep). The fans spin, screen works; but stuck. I have a corsair H80i and have customized the LED color to blue, which only works when the application is loaded. But when it gets stuck, this is the default white, suggesting that applications might not be loaded yet.

The issue has persisted across many windows 10 builds.

Comment: Is you BIOS updated to the latest version?

Comment: Yep, it is at the latest version, 2702.